# Using GCM without Android or iOS

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-messaging

I am looking to implement Google GCM as the push notification provider for a service I'm writing. I noticed they have an ample amount of information on how to code on both Android and iOS. However, what if someone wanted to hook into their services from another platform? What if someone wanted to hook into their services from a WebApplication, I can't seem to find any information on connecting without the use of their Android/iOS SDKs. I did try and Google for it, but all I could find were various client libraries/sample code that demonstrate how to dispatch messages to GCM, but not receive on a client device. Is this even possible? Can someone provide some documentation/example code? It would be very beneficial.

Comment: Currently GCM supports Android, iOS and Chrome clients. Here are some docs for GCM on Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm

Comment: Darn that is unfortunate. I really hope they open up more options down the road.